# Python nested loop sending emails

Tags: python, loops, nested-loops

I have a list like [['email', 'password', 'host', 'port'],  ['email1', 'password1', 'host1', 'port1']
and a list of 10 emails like ['email1', 'email2', 'email3', 'email4', 'email5', 'email6', 'email7, 'email8', 'email9', 'email10']

now i want to make a loop that will first login to a email using smtp then send email to the first 5 emails from the second list then login to with the second smtp of the first list then send next five email from the emails list.

How to do that using loop?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please post the source code in your question.

Comment: i tried but failed and i deleted the code, Any way i don't want the method how to send email , I just want the algorithm, how that will work

Comment: I found an answer and that works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
emails = ['lawrencelarry565@gmail.com', 'frankfrankjcastillo55@gmail.com', 'johnnyquijano55@gmail.com', 'alexanderspade55@gmail.com', 'jensentheodora641@gmail.com', 'kennethomalley55@gmail.com', 'tonireyes5555@gmail.com', 'robertgarfield55@gmail.com', 'markkeen5555@gmail.com', 'salendrinawater@gmail.com']
smtps = [['abc@gmail.com', 'abcdef', 'host', '465'], ['def@gmail.com', 'abcdef', 'host', '465']]

for item in smtps:
    i = 0
    print("Logging in to " + item[0])
    # Login method here
    while i < 5:
        print("Sending Mail to : " + emails(0))
        # sending email method here
        emails.pop(0)
        i+=1
```